# when does django run the query for a OneToOneField?

Tags: python, django, one-to-one

Hello most wise keepers of answers yet unknown to me,

I am using a one to one relationship in Django to attach some extra fields to Django's User model. However, I am wondering whether this is going to cause me to run an extra query every time that I look up a user. This is particularly concerning given that I do not always need the information in these extra fields.

I have not been able to find any information (that I could understand) on when django actually runs the queries on related fields.

does the query for a OneToOneField run as soon as I run my initial query (to get my user), or does it use some django trickery to only run if I try to access the related fields?

If the second query does run automatically, is there any way to tell django not to do that?

Thank you in advance for sharing your wisdom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like Django runs the query until you call the relation

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.OneToOneField(Bar)
```

in shell:

```
In [1]: Bar.objects.create(name='chocolate')
Out[1]: <Bar: Bar object>
In [2]: Foo.objects.create(bar=Out[1])
Out[2]: <Foo: Foo object>
In [3]: from django.db import connection
In [4]: connection.queries
Out[4]:
[{u'sql': u"QUERY = u'BEGIN' - PARAMS = ()", u'time': u'0.000'},
 {u'sql': u'QUERY = u\'INSERT INTO "myapp_bar" ("name") VALUES (%s)\' - PARAMS = (u\'chochalate\',)',
  u'time': u'0.001'},
 {u'sql': u"QUERY = u'BEGIN' - PARAMS = ()", u'time': u'0.000'},
 {u'sql': u'QUERY = u\'INSERT INTO "myapp_foo" ("bar_id") VALUES (%s)\' - PARAMS = (1,)',
  u'time': u'0.001'}]
In [5]: foo = Foo.objects.all()
In [6]: foo
Out[6]: [<Foo: Foo object>]
In [7]: connection.queries
Out[7]:
[
 # ... same as above ...
 {u'sql': u'QUERY = u\'SELECT "myapp_foo"."id", "myapp_foo"."bar_id" FROM "myapp_foo" LIMIT 21\' - PARAMS = ()',
  u'time': u'0.000'}] # bar is not queried 
In [8]: foo.bar
Out[8]: <Bar: Bar object>

In [9]: connection.queries
Out[9]:
[
 # ... same as above ...
 {u'sql': u'QUERY = u\'SELECT "myapp_bar"."id", "myapp_bar"."name" FROM "myapp_bar" WHERE "myapp_bar"."id" = %s LIMIT 21\' - PARAMS = (1,)',
  u'time': u'0.000'}] # now bar is queried
```

Comment: Does it call every time the relation is accessed?

Comment: It doesn't look like any more queries are made for calling it again. It looks like Django dynamically adds it to the instance after the first time.

Comment: So, django caches the result and doesn't make the same query again... Hmmm... I wonder what happens if the related object changes....

Comment: The change will not be reflected in that instance

Comment: awesome. thanks. I knew there had to be some kind of tool to see the actual queries that django was making, but I didn't know what it was.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar. It's also a helpful feature for this kind of thing.